# Error during install of mysql2 gem for ruby 2.0.0 on Windows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, compilation, rubygems

I'm trying to install the `mysql2` gem for Ruby 2.0.0.

I tried following the instructions at http://rorguide.blogspot.hk/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html, but was not successful. Given the error message below, can anyone help me resolve this error?

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.
3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.6/ext/mysql2/ge
m_make.out
```

My ruby was downloaded from here:

http://rubyinstaller.org/

***EDIT***

```
C:\xampp\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0>gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib
="c:\xampp\mysql\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\xampp\mysql\include" --with-mysql
-config="c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql_config.exe"'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-lib="c:\xampp\mysql\lib" --with-m
ysql-include="c:\xampp\mysql\include" --with-mysql-config="c:/xampp/mysql/bin/my
sql_config.exe"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-lib="c:\xampp\mysq
l\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\xampp\mysql\include" --with-mysql-config="c:/xam
pp/mysql/bin/mysql_config.exe"
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do': The compiler failed
 to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:516:in `try_link0'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:531:in `try_link'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:717:in `try_func'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1001:in `block in have_
func'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:892:in `block in checki
ng_for'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block (2 levels
) in postpone'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block in postpo
ne'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:333:in `postpone'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `checking_for'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1000:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems
/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ex
t/mysql2/gem_make.out

C:\xampp\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0>gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib
="c:/xampp/mysql/lib" --with-mysql-include="c:/xampp/mysql/include" --with-mysql
-config="c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql_config.exe"'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-lib="c:/xampp/mysql/lib" --with-m
ysql-include="c:/xampp/mysql/include" --with-mysql-config="c:/xampp/mysql/bin/my
sql_config.exe"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-lib="c:/xampp/mysq
l/lib" --with-mysql-include="c:/xampp/mysql/include" --with-mysql-config="c:/xam
pp/mysql/bin/mysql_config.exe"
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do': The compiler failed
 to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:516:in `try_link0'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:531:in `try_link'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:717:in `try_func'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1001:in `block in have_
func'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:892:in `block in checki
ng_for'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block (2 levels
) in postpone'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block in postpo
ne'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:333:in `postpone'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `checking_for'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1000:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems
/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ex
t/mysql2/gem_make.out

C:\xampp\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0>gem install mysql -- '--with-mysql-lib=
"c:/xampp/mysql/lib" --with-mysql-include="c:/xampp/mysql/include" --with-mysql-
config="c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql_config.exe"'
Fetching: mysql-2.9.1.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-lib="c:/xampp/mysql/lib" --with-m
ysql-include="c:/xampp/mysql/include" --with-mysql-config="c:/xampp/mysql/bin/my
sql_config.exe"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-lib="c:/xampp/mysq
l/lib" --with-mysql-include="c:/xampp/mysql/include" --with-mysql-config="c:/xam
pp/mysql/bin/mysql_config.exe"
checking for main() in -llibmysql... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib
C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do': The compiler failed
 to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:516:in `try_link0'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:531:in `try_link'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:717:in `try_func'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:947:in `block in have_l
ibrary'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:892:in `block in checki
ng_for'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block (2 levels
) in postpone'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block in postpo
ne'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:333:in `postpone'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `checking_for'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `have_library'
        from extconf.rb:27:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems
/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/
mysql_api/gem_make.out

C:\xampp\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0>gem install mysql -- '--with-mysql-lib=
"c:/xampp/mysql/lib" --with-mysql-include="c:/xampp/mysql/include" --with-mysql-
config="c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql_config"'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-lib="c:/xampp/mysql/lib" --with-m
ysql-include="c:/xampp/mysql/include" --with-mysql-config="c:/xampp/mysql/bin/my
sql_config"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-lib="c:/xampp/mysq
l/lib" --with-mysql-include="c:/xampp/mysql/include" --with-mysql-config="c:/xam
pp/mysql/bin/mysql_config"
checking for main() in -llibmysql... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib
C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do': The compiler failed
 to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:516:in `try_link0'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:531:in `try_link'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:717:in `try_func'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:947:in `block in have_l
ibrary'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:892:in `block in checki
ng_for'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block (2 levels
) in postpone'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block in postpo
ne'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:333:in `postpone'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `checking_for'
        from C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `have_library'
        from extconf.rb:27:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems
/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/xampp/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/
mysql_api/gem_make.out

C:\xampp\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0>
```

Comment: Please remove the single quotes around the rubygems arguments, should read: `gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-lib=...` Take a look to this article: http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/ and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5368767/117298

Comment: One last thing: you're installing a 64bits version of Ruby, so you need 64bits versions of the DLLs. Most likely xampp don't ship those. I strongly recommend you use the 32bits version of Ruby 2.0.0 unless you have really high memory usage requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
```

you are missing libmysql-headers.

edit: is duplicate of: [Installing mysql-2.9.0 gem on Windows fails due to lack of libmysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604362/installing-mysql-2-9-0-gem-on-windows-fails-due-to-lack-of-libmysql)

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604362/installing-mysql-2-9-0-gem-on-windows-fails-due-to-lack-of-libmysql

Comment: did you set the right path for --with-opt-lib= and --with-opt-include=  when running gem install?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29175/discussion-between-tecjam-and-hkinterview)

Comment: checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***

Comment: Do you have Ruby's DevKit installed? https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Comment: the error is now similar to http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?116,178217,178217#msg-178217, but i'm on windows

Comment: try gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=..../bin/mysql_config but edit the path of mysql_config

Comment: it says "You have to install development tools first.". it cant find development tools

Answer (score 0):

your error clearly stated that it is regarding to your `Devkit`
So you can download devkit from

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads

and follow the steps from

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

this will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

**llibmysql error** means ruby can't see libmysql.dll. I got the error just now, so I`ve copied libmySQL.dll to $mysqldir/lib and got another error

```
checking for main() in -llibmysql... yes
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
-----
mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
```

So, now ruby can see libmysql.dll, but now it needs mysql files. I launch mysql installator again and select, that I need include files. 2minutues - and I got includes directory. Launch `gem install mysql2....` again and got `1 gem installed`.

Answer (score 0):

If like me, you have some coworker working on a rails project using Windows (in my case Windows 7).
 In order to install the gem “mysql2″ you need to specify in the command line the path to use the libraries.

Pre-requisite: Having MYSQL installed.

Command line to run (replace the path by your installation path)

```
 gem install mysql2 — ‘–with-mysql-lib=”c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib” –with-mysql-include=”c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include”‘
```