# Windows Rails Server issue with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am starting with Ruby on Rails and installed Ruby, DevKit, RubyGems, Rails, MySQL (with everything it asked for as Visual Studio, etc.) and RubyGem. It wasn't without complications, but I finally somehow made it and then I came to issue that I wasn't able to solve.

I created app with command: `rails new my_app -d mysql`
It passed well and then I tried to start server with command: `rails server`
And it fails ending with this message:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. 
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I also tried to create app with SQLite, so just `rails new my_app` and then it works. So problem is obviously with MySQL.

Additional information:

- I installed exactly this installation [MySQL Installer 5.6.22, type: "Default Development"](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.6.html)
- My system is W8.1 Pro X64 with all updates.
- Ruby 2.1.5p273 [x64-mingw32]
- RubyGem 2.4.5
- Rails 4.2.0

BTW I also copied `libmysql.dll` from `\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib` to `\Ruby21-x64\bin`

PS: I know about the option with virtual Linux system, but I would rather make it work directly on Windows, if it isn't imposible.

Thank You!

**Edit- Added the command prompt output:**

Here I added only part of it, cause here is very low limit for size of the answer. Because of that I uploaded full output to txt file in here - [www.mega.co.nz/rails_server_error-full_command_prompt_output.txt](https://mega.co.nz/#!uMkSwCZS!wb4X42TWaAqb1DPbAgv-L0FtCSH1BLncGqXVecdEJjQ)

```
  546 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/exception.rb
  547 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/syntax_error.rb
  548 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x64-mingw32/psych.so
  549 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/omap.rb
  550 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/set.rb
  551 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/class_loader.rb
  552 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/scalar_scanner.rb
  553 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/nodes/node.rb
  554 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/nodes/stream.rb
  555 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/nodes/document.rb
  556 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/nodes/sequence.rb
  557 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/nodes/scalar.rb
  558 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/nodes/mapping.rb
  559 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/nodes/alias.rb
  560 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/nodes.rb
  561 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/streaming.rb
  562 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb
  563 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb
  564 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/emitter.rb
  565 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/handler.rb
  566 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/tree_builder.rb
  567 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb
  568 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/json/ruby_events.rb
  569 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/json_tree.rb
  570 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/depth_first.rb
  571 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors.rb
  572 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/parser.rb
  573 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/coder.rb
  574 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/core_ext.rb
  575 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/deprecated.rb
  576 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/stream.rb
  577 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/json/yaml_events.rb
  578 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/json/tree_builder.rb
  579 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/json/stream.rb
  580 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/handlers/document_stream.rb
  581 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb
  582 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/yaml.rb
  583 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/dire
ctive_processor.rb
  584 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/safe
ty_colons.rb
  585 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/char
set_normalizer.rb
  586 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/sass
_compressor.rb
  587 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/yui_
compressor.rb
  588 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/clos
ure_compressor.rb
  589 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/ugli
fier_compressor.rb
  590 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/sass
_template.rb
  591 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/scss
_template.rb
  592 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets.rb
  593 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/erro
rs.rb
  594 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_supp
ort/benchmarkable.rb
  595 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/active_model_helper.rb
  596 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/asset_url_helper.rb
  597 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/capture_helper.rb
  598 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/output_safety_helper.rb
  599 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/tag_helper.rb
  600 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/asset_tag_helper.rb
  601 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/atom_feed_helper.rb
  602 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/cache_helper.rb
  603 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/controller_helper.rb
  604 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/csrf_helper.rb
  605 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/date_helper.rb
  606 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/debug_helper.rb
  607 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/javascript_helper.rb
  608 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/url_helper.rb
  609 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.1/lib/rail
s/html/sanitizer/version.rb
  610 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/2.1/nokogiri.so
  611 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/version.rb
  612 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/syntax_error.rb
  613 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/pp/node.rb
  614 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/pp/character_data.rb
  615 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/pp.rb
  616 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/parse_options.rb
  617 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/sax/document.rb
  618 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/sax/parser_context.rb
  619 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/sax/parser.rb
  620 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/sax/push_parser.rb
  621 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/sax.rb
  622 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/node/save_options.rb
  623 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/node.rb
  624 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/attribute_decl.rb
  625 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/element_decl.rb
  626 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/element_content.rb
  627 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/character_data.rb
  628 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/namespace.rb
  629 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/attr.rb
  630 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/dtd.rb
  631 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/cdata.rb
  632 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/text.rb
  633 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/document.rb
  634 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/document_fragment.rb
  635 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/processing_instruction.rb
  636 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/node_set.rb
  637 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/syntax_error.rb
  638 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/xpath/syntax_error.rb
  639 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/xpath.rb
  640 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/xpath_context.rb
  641 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/builder.rb
  642 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/reader.rb
  643 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/notation.rb
  644 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/entity_decl.rb
  645 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/schema.rb
  646 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml/relax_ng.rb
  647 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xml.rb
  648 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xslt/stylesheet.rb
  649 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/xslt.rb
  650 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/html/entity_lookup.rb
  651 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/html/document.rb
  652 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/html/document_fragment.rb
  653 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/html/sax/parser_context.rb
  654 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/html/sax/parser.rb
  655 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/html/sax/push_parser.rb
  656 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/html/element_description.rb
  657 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/html/element_description_defaults.rb
  658 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/html.rb
  659 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/decorators/slop.rb
  660 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/css/node.rb
  661 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/css/xpath_visitor.rb
  662 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x64-mingw32/racc/cparse.so
  663 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/racc/parser.rb
  664 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/css/parser_extras.rb
  665 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/css/parser.rb
  666 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/css/tokenizer.rb
  667 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/css/syntax_error.rb
  668 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/css.rb
  669 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri/html/builder.rb
  670 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/noko
giri.rb
  671 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah/metahelpers
.rb
  672 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah/elements.rb

  673 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah/html5/white
list.rb
  674 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah/html5/scrub
.rb
  675 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah/scrubber.rb

  676 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah/scrubbers.r
b
  677 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah/instance_me
thods.rb
  678 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah/xml/documen
t.rb
  679 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah/xml/documen
t_fragment.rb
  680 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah/html/docume
nt.rb
  681 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah/html/docume
nt_fragment.rb
  682 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah.rb
  683 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.1/lib/rail
s/html/scrubbers.rb
  684 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.1/lib/rail
s/html/sanitizer.rb
  685 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.1/lib/rail
s-html-sanitizer.rb
  686 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/sanitize_helper.rb
  687 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/text_helper.rb
  688 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/form_tag_helper.rb
  689 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/mo
del_naming.rb
  690 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/form_helper.rb
  691 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/form_options_helper.rb
  692 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_supp
ort/number_helper.rb
  693 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/number_helper.rb
  694 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_supp
ort/core_ext/module/concerning.rb
  695 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_supp
ort/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb
  696 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_supp
ort/core_ext/module.rb
  697 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/re
cord_identifier.rb
  698 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/record_tag_helper.rb
  699 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/rendering_helper.rb
  700 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_supp
ort/core_ext/string/access.rb
  701 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/translation_helper.rb
  702 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers.rb
  703 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets
/rails/helper.rb
  704 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets
/rails/version.rb
  705 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine/con
figuration.rb
  706 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/source_ann
otation_extractor.rb
  707 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/applicatio
n/configuration.rb
  708 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets
/railtie.rb
  709 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/all.rb
  710 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2/version.rb

  711 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2/error.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: Please add the complete command line output of the command `rails server`

Comment: I added all I could see in Command Prompt when it finished.

Comment: @AmitThawait Actually I found the way to copy here all, but then I got this error - "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 79828"

Comment: Finally I got idea to upload copy of that to txt file, so here you can get really full output - [link](https://mega.co.nz/#!uMkSwCZS!wb4X42TWaAqb1DPbAgv-L0FtCSH1BLncGqXVecdEJjQ)

Comment: try changing `gem 'mysql2'` to `gem 'mysql'` in the Gemfile , then run `bundle install` and start the rails server

Comment: `Bundle install` failed when I changed it to `gem mysql` and then `rails server` didn't even start for missing gem `'mysql (>= 0) x64-mingw32'`. Bundle was completed only when I fixed back to `gem mysql2`. Here is the full output - [link](https://mega.co.nz/#!6BkxAB7b!GmxbdbqJRwvwpD3Yic5dz88h8JxW3y8nABapAVQuDLo)

Comment: Please follow this link to install `mysql` gem in windows : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673612/installing-mysql-ruby-gem-in-windows-fails-using-ruby-2-0-0

Comment: I tried every answer from that page, but nothing worked for me. When I finished any of that solutions, then I wasn't able to install new app. Only if I first reinstalled mysql2 - `gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include"'` and only then I could successfully run `rails new my_app -d mysql`, but then `rails server` failed in same way as before.